# how to create a stream from an in-memory buffer

Tags: rust, rust-tokio

I am reading from `STDIN` into a big buffer (`BytesMut`) in memory, I am using something like this:

```rust
use anyhow::Result;
use bytes::{BufMut, BytesMut};
use futures::stream::TryStreamExt;
use tokio::io::stdin;
use tokio_util::codec::{BytesCodec, FramedRead};

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<()> {
    let mut buffer = BytesMut::with_capacity(1024 * 1024 * 512);
    let mut input_stream = FramedRead::new(stdin(), BytesCodec::new());
    while let Some(bytes) = input_stream.try_next().await? {
        buffer.put(bytes);
    }
    println!("buf: {}", buffer.len());
    Ok(())
}
```

`buffer` now contains the full input, but how can I create a stream from it?

I want a `stream` because I would like to `POST` in streams instead of just trying to push the whole buffer by using the `reqwest` create using something like:

```
 let client = reqwest::Client::new();
 let body = reqwest::Body::wrap_stream(stream);
 client.post().body(body)
```

In my naive attempt, I thought that passing the buffer as an argument for `FrameRead` it could work, something like:

```
let mut output_stream = FramedRead::new(buffer, BytesCodec::new());
```

But that gives the error:

```
the trait bound `bytes::BytesMut: tokio::io::AsyncRead` is not satisfied
```

Then I found in the `AsyncRead` docs that there is the method [poll_read_buf](https://docs.rs/tokio/0.2.22/tokio/io/trait.AsyncRead.html#method.poll_read_buf) that may help to convert the buffer into a stream, but here is where I am stuck trying to find how to implement or create the stream from an in-memory buffer.

My current try is with the create [async-stream](https://crates.io/crates/async-stream) with something like this:

```rust
let stream = async_stream::stream! {
    while !buffer.is_empty() {
        let out = if buffer.len() > 8192 {
            buffer.split_to(8192)
        } else {
            buffer.split_to(buffer.len())
        };
        yield out.freeze();
    }
};
```

I think that I am getting close but that returns:

```
 --> src/main.rs:32:46
   |
32 |     let body = Body::wrap_stream(Bytes::from(stream));
   |                                              ^^^^^^ the trait `std::convert::From<async_stream::AsyncStream<bytes::Bytes, impl std::future::Future>>` is not implemented for `bytes::Bytes`
   |
   = help: the following implementations were found:
             <bytes::Bytes as std::convert::From<&'static [u8]>>
             <bytes::Bytes as std::convert::From<&'static str>>
             <bytes::Bytes as std::convert::From<bytes::BytesMut>>
             <bytes::Bytes as std::convert::From<http::byte_str::ByteStr>>
           and 4 others
   = note: required by `std::convert::From::from`

error[E0277]: the trait bound `bytes::Bytes: tokio::stream::Stream` is not satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:32:34
   |
32 |     let body = Body::wrap_stream(Bytes::from(stream));
   |                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `tokio::stream::Stream` is not implemented for `bytes::Bytes`
```

How from my big in-memory buffer I could now create chunks and build/return a `Stream`?

Any ideas?

Comment: Could you use [`futures::stream::once`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.3.5/futures/stream/fn.once.html) to wrap the buffer into a stream?

Comment: I would like to create the stream in multiple chunks and not send the whole buffer in a single stream

Comment: I am confused - isn't it up to `reqwest` (and the OS and the network) _how_ it will send the stream to the server? Your stream should be concerned with _providing_ the data, and if it can provide it all at once, all the better, because it gives the sender more opportunities for optimization.

Comment: That's indeed what I would like to check, I am curious to see how it works when uploading in chunks and in one shot,  `stream::once` doesn't help me much in this test because it sends the whole buffer and I  can  indeed avoid the `wrap_stream` bypassing the buffer directly with `Body(BytesMut)`

Comment: `stream::once` should help you in the literal goal of obtaining a stream. But if `Body(BytesMut)` compiles, I think it's the right approach. If you want to be sure, you can use a tool like `strace` (use `strace -f` to capture all threads) to check how the data ends up getting transferred to the server.

Comment: I am curious about the best way too. I ended up using `futures::stream` and `futures_util::StreamExt`: `stream::iter(bytes).ready_chunks(size)`. I think it is less efficient than using Bytes but I couldn't see how to do it.